# how to move this jquery menu where i want it?

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

im trying to position this menu a little more to the top and centered
i tried tweaking lots of the css and still nothing

here is my jsbin

http://jsbin.com/welcome/74921/

```
body{
            background:#333 url(bg.jpg) repeat top left;
            font-family:Arial;
        }
        span.reference{
            position:fixed;
            left:10px;
            bottom:10px;
            font-size:12px;
        }
        span.reference a{
            color:#aaa;
            text-transform:uppercase;
            text-decoration:none;
            text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
            margin-right:30px;
        }
        span.reference a:hover{
            color:#ddd;
        }
        ul.sdt_menu{
            margin-top:50px;
        }
        h1.title{
            text-indent:-9000px;
            background:transparent url(title.png) no-repeat top left;
            width:633px;
            height:69px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ul.sdt_menu {
  margin: YOURTOPVALUEHERE auto 0 auto;
  display: table;
  width: auto; /* or remove your width value (better) */
}
```

Comment: na it doesnt center it, the other solution given by dioedeous works but in ie it eats the right margin preety much making the menu sticked to the right when minimized

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.sdt_menu {
    margin-top: 150px; <--- get rid of this
    margin-left:auto; <-- add this
    margin-right:auto;  <-- add this
}
```